# Log4j Configuration File path

Tags: grails, log4j

We are working on grails and also have microservices. There is a logging service in grails folder and **log4j2.xml** in grails-app/conf. Now we want to migrate logging service to jar(means outside of grails to one of microservices). So added **log4j.xml** in our resources folder of maven project. But it is not detecting the configuration file, so logging  only to consoles.
Tried several things like
1. Setting system property in code 
2. renaming log4j.xml file as log4j2.xml (but it gives error in grails startup)

Edit: Project Structure

```
Project    
|  
+-- grails-app
|   |  
|   +-- conf
|       |
|       +--log4j2.xml
|   +-- services/OldLoggingService.groovy 
|
+--logevent(mavenproject)
|   |  
|   +-- src/main/groovy/com/log/LogEventProducer.groovy
|   +-- src/main/resources/log4j.xml
```

[xml configuration file link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CYox.png)

it is not showing any error (just writing logs to console only)